# LC filter for Vref and Vadc

Tags: adc, filter, passive-networks

I'm reading an Atmel Data-sheet and it mentions using an LC filter for the Vref and Vadc pins, when simulating a simple small AC voltage with a 5V offset and using an LC filter with 10uH and 10uF the attenuation stays at 0dB until the SRF is hit at about 15.8kHz. The signal only starts to drop after that point, am I right assuming these types of filters are only meant for really high frequencies? (In power supply terms at least)

Also, if you get noise at the SRF of your filter won't that create other problems?

Comment: You really should leave a little time before accepting a answer, since you don't know what others might have said that now aren't going to bother.

Comment: Most modern ADCs have fairly sharply switching sample-and-hold circuits, with the result that noise well above the sampling frequency's nyquist limit can alias down to baseband, so filtering out higher frequency noise really does make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rolloff frequency of a LC filter is \$ f = \dfrac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{LC}}\$.

When L is in Henries, C in Farads, then f is in Hz.  This comes out to 15.9 kHz for 10 µH and 10 µF, so your simulation is apparently correct.

Just like RC filters, LC filters can be arranged for frequencies over a wide range since inductors and capacitors come in a wide range of values.  They are not inherently "high" or "low".

Often the DC level of a power supply is pretty good but has high frequency noise on it, like from a switching power supply and high frequency components of switching transients.  Sometimes these are filtered with a small chip inductor in series followed by a ceramic cap to ground.  The rolloff frequency may be a few 10s of kHz, but the noise is much higher than that.  Lots of analog chips have pretty good power supply rejection capability, but since this is done with active electronics it fails at high frequencies.  As long as the power supply filter removes the high frequencies the electronics can't handle, things will work well enough.

Comment: So the 10uH and 100nF recommended by Atmel is good enough and I should stop worrying? Thanks Olin.